# Matlab: Parameter fit of ODE45 equation - only initial value for xdata

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, differential-equations

I have a system of 3 ODEs:

```
Cf' = kin * Cw * F - (kout + km) * Cf
Cw' = kout * Cf - kin * Cw(i) * F
Cm' = km * Cf
```

I measured data for all time points of Cf and only the initial values of Cw and Cm. Now I would like to fit my model to this data, finding the best parameter values for kin,kout and km.

Can I do this somehow with lsqcurvefit and ode45?
Thank you!

Comment: What is F? What does Cw(i) mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you got an ODE function

```
function Dy = derivs(t,y,p)
  Cf = y(1); Cw = y(2); Cm = y(3);
  kin = p(1); kout = p(2); km = p(3);
  DCf = kin * Cw * F - (kout + km) * Cf;
  DCw = kout * Cf - kin * Cw * F;
  DCm = km * Cf;
  Dy = [ DCf DCw DCm ]
end
```

and a function to get solutions for specified points

```
function y_data = solution(x_data,y0,p)
  sol = ode45(@(t,y)derivs(t,y,p), [x0,xe], y0)
  y_data = deval(sol, x_data)
end
```

Now the function to pass to the fitting procedure is

```
@(p) solution(x_data,y0,p)
```

and you get a more detailed value table with the optimized parameters `p_opt` for plotting by

```
x_plot = linspace(x0,xe,300)
y_plot = solution(x_plot,y0,p_opt)
plot(x_plot, y_plot)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Where in this procedure is the actual fitting? Do I have to add lsqcurvefit somewhere?

Comment: Yes. This was all just about the input for the fitting procedure. You now need to find out what the actual interface is and if necessary adapt this. Check also if `F` is a not renamed `Cf`.